# Hibernate versioning with OracleDB 11g "_" invalid character

Tags: java, database, hibernate, oracle11g, versioning

Using hibernate with Oracle db 11g express edition release 2.

When using the annotation `@Versioned` for a table "`Organizations`" for example,

hibernate seems to try to create a table `Public.Organizations_versions` with some columns.

The problem is that some of those columns (`_revision`, `_revision_type`) start with an underscore 
and Oracle db does not allow creating a table with columns who start with underscore.

Any solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: this @Versioned annotation seems to come from hibernate envers

Comment: I had not problem using Envers and an Oracle database. Aren't you using a very old version of Envers ?

Comment: trying to use hibernate's setNamingStrategy without success so far

Answer (score 0):

Change your Envers version.
If I remember, version 1.0.0 is a very old one.
Use at least :

```
1.2.2.GA-hibernate3.3
```

Here is an extract from the [Envers FAQ](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EnversFAQ?_sscc=t) :

For the current, **Hibernate-4/3.6** compatible versions, you should use the new group and artifact ids. Use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0-Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.10-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

(You'd want to match the version number with e.g. hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager)

If you want to use the older, **Hibernate-3.3** compatible versions, use the old group and artifact add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.envers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-envers</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2.GA-hibernate-3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: in the end, upgraded hibernate